# Rows not displaying properly in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, sqlite

I'm working on setting up a GUI using TKinter creating a basic program which allows me to add, update, remove and view books that I have in my personal library. I am struggling on 2 parts of the code:

1. When I click on View Records, the textbox in the GUI should show records in a list, with each item appearing on its own line.
2. It should also not duplicate the listings every time the button is pressed.

   ## The View Button

   ```
   view_records = Button(root, text="View Records", width=12, command=view_command)
   view_records.grid(row=3,column=3,columnspan=2,sticky='w’)

   def view_command():
       listings.delete(0,END) # does not duplicate entries for multiple clicks
       for row in personal_library_backend.view():
           listings.insert(END,row) # this does not list rows per index
   ```

And this is my Backend Script:

```
def insert(title, author, genre, year):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("library.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,genre,year))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("library.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

When I run the program, I keep getting an error that says "bad text index 0" on the view_command function. I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is `listings`? Is it an `Entry` widget, a `Text` widget, or a `LIstbox` widget?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that... it's a listbox.

Comment: If it's a listbox, why did you accept the answer that showed you how to update a `Text` widget?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I mean to display the item 'listings' as a list, but you are right they are contained within a Textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index of text widget should be in [one of these](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html) formats (i.e *"line.column"* or *tk.END* etc.) and your `0` doesn't fit in to any of those.

You should change delete line to:

```
listings.delete("1.0", "end") #you can use END instead of "end"
```

to delete everything in text widget.

And to make each `row` appear on new line, simply insert a new line manually after instering `row`.

```
for row in personal_library_backend.view():
    listings.insert("end", row)
    listings.insert("end","\n")
#there is an extra new line at the end, you can remove it using 
txt.delete("end-1c", "end")
```